# Cannot get a response from a Web API call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, postman, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have the following in the `TreeController` controller in a small web API:

```
    [HttpGet("GetDirectories")]
    public IActionResult GetDirectories()
    {
        var baseDir = _config["QuickShare:BaseDir"];
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseDir))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("'QuickShare:BaseDir' is not configured");
        }
        var ret = GetDirectories(baseDir); ;
        return Json(ret);
    }
    private List<DirectoryInfo> GetDirectories(string parentDir)
    {
        var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(parentDir);
        return dirInfo.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
    }
```

When I try and call this action from Postman, I get told

> Could not get any response There was an error connecting to
>   http://localhost:59243/api/Tree/GetDirectories.

Now the default, test, controller that comes with the project template is unchanged:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] {"value1", "value2"};
    }
    ...
}
```

And when I have the API running in Visual Studio, I can get a proper response from the `Values` controller, but not from the `TreeController`, yet they are almost exactly the same. And, when I call the `Tree`/GetDirectories` action, a breakpoint in that action method is hit, and I can single step through the very few lines that my method has, and they all execute fine.

The problem only becomes apparent when that last line of the action executes:

```
return Json(ret);
```

Then I get shown that Postman `Could not get any response` despite no exception being raised; while debugging the code, it looks like everything should work fine, and the requests to the `Values` controller work fine.

Comment: `JsonRequestBehavior` seems to not have made it into MVC Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action method should return either the specific result type (`JsonResult` when you return `Json` ) or `IActionResult`.

**Example:**

```
 [HttpGet("GetDirectories")]
    public JsonResult GetDirectories()
    {
        var baseDir = _config["QuickShare:BaseDir"];
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseDir))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("'QuickShare:BaseDir' is not configured");
        }
        var ret = GetDirectories(baseDir);
        return Json(ret);
    }
```

OR

```
[HttpGet("GetDirectories")]
public IActionResult GetDirectories()
{
    var baseDir = _config["QuickShare:BaseDir"];
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseDir))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("'QuickShare:BaseDir' is not configured");
    }
    var ret = GetDirectories(baseDir) ;
    return Ok(ret);
}
```

You can get more help from  Microsoft Documentation: [Formatting Response Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting)